# Convert wrong currency values in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-office, office365

I'm regularly importing a CSV file into Excel that contains some columns with currency. Unfortunately the format is so that Excel doesn't get it right when importing. This is the format:

€123.12

this probably looks okay for US citizens but the european currency standard looks more like this:

123,12 €

It looks like it's not possible to simply switch the cell format after importing. I think a search/replace using some regex should be working - unfortunately I've never done this in Excel and I still wonder if there's an Excel way to do this.

Any suggestions?

(Sidenote: I'm on Office365 for Mac if this is of any relevance here)

Comment: Is the cell format `€123.12` and the actual data is `123.12` ? or the actual data is a string in the format `€123.12`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom formatting like this:

```
#.##0,00 €
```